# How to find the nearest 100 meters latitude and longitude depending upon the current location in objective c, Iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, latitude-longitude

How to find the nearest 100 meters latitude and longitude depending upon the current location, i have created a database in SQLITE3 which consists of set of latitudes and longitudes and corresponding there location name. Depending upon the current location i want to fetch the nearest 100 meters latitude and longitude in objective C,
I am using the following code to get the Current location,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    databaseName = @"searchdata.sql";

    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath = [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

    [self checkAndCreateDatabase];
    [self readDataFromDatabase];
    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    int degrees = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    double decimal = fabs(newLocation.coordinate.latitude - degrees);
    int minutes = decimal * 60;
    double seconds = decimal * 3600 - minutes * 60;
    NSString *lat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d° %d' %1.4f\"", 
                     degrees, minutes, seconds];
    NSLog(@" Current Latitude : %@",lat);
    //latLabel.text = lat;
    degrees = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    decimal = fabs(newLocation.coordinate.longitude - degrees);
    minutes = decimal * 60;
    seconds = decimal * 3600 - minutes * 60;
    NSString *longt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d° %d' %1.4f\"", 
                       degrees, minutes, seconds];
    NSLog(@" Current Longitude : %@",longt);
    //longLabel.text = longt;
}
```

so how to fetch or how to calculate the surrounding 100 meters latitudes and longitudes and display it.

Thanks for the help I am using the following formula

```
     -(double)kilometresBetweenPlace1:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) place1 andPlace2:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) place2 {

    double dlon = convertToRadians([pLong intValue] - [longt intValue]);
    double dlat = convertToRadians([pLat intValue] - [lat intValue]);

    double a = ( pow(sin(dlat / 2), 2) + cos(convertToRadians([lat intValue]))) * cos(convertToRadians([pLat intValue])) * pow(sin(dlon / 2), 2);
    double angle = 2 * asin(sqrt(a));
      return angle * RADIO;
}
```

and getting the following output 8505.369547 on return, i am just confused what is the value i am getting actually.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your questions. What you mean by "nearest 100 meters latitude and longitude"? Are you looking for points in your database that are within 100 meters? Please be specific.

Comment: @sosborn ya I am looking for points in my database that are within 100 meters.

Comment: Latitudes and Longitudes are equally spaced as a grid. So, from the current location, there are only four possibilities of points that are within 100m from that point. You can do this by simple reasoning and a little math

Comment: @shasha Can you please post the working code here, I am also facing the same problem..

Comment: @Developer The Edit is the working code in the answers, I am using that code only.

Comment: Are u finding all the locations around 100m or only one location?

Comment: all the locations which are in my database within 100 meters

Comment: But I need only one location and I dnt have any DB

Comment: @shasha could u please share your version of the code. I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the CoreLocation framework can help you with this issue? It seems the following method is made with your question in mind:

```
- (id)initCircularRegionWithCenter:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)center radius:(CLLocationDistance)radius identifier:(NSString *)identifier
```

You could test if a coordinate from your database falls within a region by using the following method:

```
- (BOOL)containsCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
```

I guess the above ain't ideal when your database contains a lot of locations. But perhaps one can filter out a set of locations to test based on some minimum and maximum latitude / longitude values.

---

**Edit:** as requested, an example (don't forget to import the *CoreLocation* framework):

```
- (void)startTest
{

#define COORDS_COUNT 4
#define RADIUS       10000.0f

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coords[COORDS_COUNT] = {
        CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.000004, 4.100002),
        CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(53.000009, 4.000003),
        CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.000001, 4.500008),
        CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.000002, 3.900900),
    };

    CLLocationCoordinate2D center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.0f, 4.0f); // Amsterdam
    CLRegion *region = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:center radius:RADIUS identifier:@"Amsterdam"];

    for (int i = 0; i < COORDS_COUNT; i++)
    {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = coords[i];
        if ([region containsCoordinate:coord])
        {
            NSLog(@"location %f, %f is within %.0f meters of coord %f, %f", coord.latitude, coord.longitude, RADIUS, center.latitude, center.longitude);
        }
        else 
        {
            NSLog(@"location %f, %f is not within %.0f meters of coord %f, %f", coord.latitude, coord.longitude, RADIUS, center.latitude, center.longitude);        
        }
    }

}
```

---

**Edit 2:** I realize it's not exactly the answer you requested, but it seems to me this is what you need. As you can imagine the nearest 100 meters latitude / longitude near any coordinate consists of an virtually unlimited amount of coordinates in a circular region. My guess is you want to find objects within your database that are nearby some coordinate and the above code should help you achieve this. You can retrieve a set of results from your database and test if they are nearby some coordinate.

---

**Edit 3:** The following code is likely exactly what you need:

```
CLLocation *center = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:52.0f longitude:4.0f]; // Amsterdam
CLLocation *location1 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:52.000004f longitude:4.100002f];

CLLocationDistance distance = [center distanceFromLocation:location1];
NSLog(@"%f", distance);
```

---

**Edit 4:** with regards to your question about the custom object for your table view, use something like this:

```
@interface Location : NSObject 
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString               *name;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D  coordinate;
@end


@implementation Location
@synthesize name, coordinate;
@end
```

Comment: Can you help me with some more details like how to implement the method you told, i am confused like, whether i am missing any other method or functions, should i add the mapkit to the project to implement the method you told, is there any sample or reference so that i can get clear idea to develop. This is my first app developing on Location Based Service.

Comment: I am using the code which u provided in the Edit1 to check whether the latitudes and longitudes which are in my database are within 100 meters or not, in my log it is giving correctly which are within 100 meters and which are not within 100 meters, but when i am trying show it on the UITable view, it is showing all the latitudes and longitudes, but i need to display only those latitudes and longitudes which comes with in 100 meters, How to achieve this.

Comment: Add the valid results to an array and use this array as the datasource of the table view.

Comment: I have created the array and also data is there in that, the following is the code i have written,[resultArray addObject:coordString];
            NSLog(@"data in resultArray %@",resultArray); the output i am getting is "12.920684,77.560036" but i need to pass the corresponding name of the latitude and longitude to the table, how can i do this. the name, latitude, longitude values are in database which i am using.

Comment: Create a custom object that contains all properties you need and create an array of these custom objects.

Comment: I tried creating the custom object and passing, but not getting expected value.Can you please send me any link so that I can get a clear.