# Determine if Point is within radius

Tags: iphone, objective-c

What is the best way to determine if a point X is in the 100 meter radius of point Y?

Is there a method on CLLocation?

Thanks

Comment: calculate the distance between the two lat/long and compare with 100 so see if it is less than 100 for your case.

Comment: The CoreLocation framework contains methods to figure this out, assuming you're working with coordinates of latitudes and longitudes. Check this post out for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029445/how-to-find-the-nearest-100-meters-latitude-and-longitude-depending-upon-the-cur/9031836#9031836

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see

```
- (CLLocationDistance) distanceFromLocation:(const CLLocation *)location
```

[documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007126)

It calculates the distance from another `CLLocation` object.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method:

```
// proximity distance calculation
static const double kDegToRad = 0.017453292519943295769236907684886;
static const double kEarthRadiusM = 6372797.560856;

+ (double)distanceInMetersFromLoc:(CLLocation *)from toLoc:(CLLocation *)to
{
    return kEarthRadiusM * [self radianArcFrom:from.coordinate to:to.coordinate];
}

+ (double)radianArcFrom:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)from to:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)to
{
    double latitudeArc  = (from.latitude - to.latitude) * kDegToRad;
    double longitudeArc = (from.longitude - to.longitude) * kDegToRad;
    double latitudeHS = sin(latitudeArc * 0.5);
    latitudeHS *= latitudeHS;
    double lontitudeHS = sin(longitudeArc * 0.5);
    lontitudeHS *= lontitudeHS;
    double factor = cos(from.latitude * kDegToRad) * cos(to.latitude * kDegToRad);  
    return 2.0 * asin(sqrt(latitudeHS + factor * lontitudeHS));
}
```

Compare the distance as

```
if([distanceInMetersFromLoc:location1 to:location2] < 100)
{
   // your condition is satisfied. you can write your code here
}
```